# How to compare Bayes nets and Deep learning networks from performance vs explainability tradeoffs?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian-network

Machine learning models with higher performance are often based on more complex algorithms and therefore lack interpretability or explainability and vice versa. How to compare the two important subsets in machine learning from this point of view?

Comment: One could benchmark a normalised relative importance against a baseline model, i.e., a model that is known to be explainable well. Closer other models get to this importance are better "explainable". It may get a bit more difficult depending on explanation methods.